# Get Sum of all Distinct in a week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am wondering where exactly i am not clear with this query. I want to get the count of all distinct RepIDs that worked in a particular week. This is In SQL Server 2005. Thank you!!

This query gives me distinct RepID's for the whole week. I want to count RepID twice if he has records on 2 different days but count only once even if he has more than 1 record for any partiular day.. I hope i am clear. I am sorry that i was not clear before! Thank you!

```
Select count(distinct(RepID)) as SalesPeople from DailyInfo
where Date > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) 
     and Date < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
```

Comment: What is wrong with this query???

Comment: Please state your question/problem. What output are you getting, what is your input, what did you expect? Give us *something* to work with...

Comment: @Dems, I edited my question. Sorry for not being clear the first time! Thanks for the time!

Comment: @Ram: If you want to count it twice, why do you use `DISTINCT` at all? Do you want to count it only once per day?

Comment: @TimSchmelter distinct for the day not for the week is what i meant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make unique combinations of the RepID+Date to make it unique ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e83a/3)):

```
  SELECT COUNT(distinct RIGHT(DateDiff(d,0,Date),10)
                       +RIGHT(RepID,10)) as SalesPeople
    FROM DailyInfo
   WHERE Date > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date)
     AND Date < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date);
```

I have assumed `DailyInfo.Date` *can* contain time information. You can swap `DateDiff(d,0,Date)` above for just `Date`.  Similarly, `CAST(DateDiff(d,0,Date) as datetime)` below can be just `Date.

Below is the query if you needed to see the breakdown for each day.

```
  SELECT CAST(DateDiff(d,0,Date) as datetime) TheDay,
         COUNT(distinct RepID) as SalesPeople
    FROM DailyInfo
   WHERE Date > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date)
     AND Date < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
GROUP BY CAST(DateDiff(d,0,Date) as datetime) -- by day
ORDER BY TheDay
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this by suggesting how you should think about the problem.  You are looking for the number of reps per day.  So, your query should have a summary (subquery) at this level.  Then, you can count the number of days per week.

Assuming that your date does not have any time component, you can use the following:

```
select count(*)
from (select RepId, date as thedate, count(*) as NumOnDay
      from DailyInfo
      group by RepId, date
      where Date > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) 
           and Date < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
     ) rd
```

Alternatively, you could count the number of days that a rep worked during a week and then add these up:

```
select sum(numdates)
from (select RepId, count(distinct date) as numdates
      from DailyInfo
      group by RepId 
      where Date > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) 
           and Date < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
     ) rd
```

If your `date` field has a time component, then you need to remove the time component for this to work.  Or use some trick such as `day(date)`, since the day function will returns a different value for each date in a week.  In later versions of SQL Server, you can just `cast(date as date)`, if the original date is datetime.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi . . . Thank you, I adjusted the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(1)
from DailyInfo
group by convert(varchar(10),[date], 120) 
where [put your condition here]
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, and `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`, not after.

Comment: Also please add an explanation of why this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE, but might be over kill. And have the group by the day in the CTE and you need to do is a sum of the totals.

```
WITH cte ([day], total) as
(
    Select DATENAME(DW,[Date]), count(distinct(RepID)) as SalesPeople from DailyInfo
    where [Date] > DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) and [Date] < DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
    GROUP BY DATENAME(DW,[Date])
)
select SUM(total) FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what I think you want you need to group by day, and filter on the week, and then do a distinct on the result:

```
 Select Distinct(RepID) 
 From (Select RepID
       Group By DateDiff(day, 0, Date)
       From DailyInfo
       Where Date > DateAdd(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @Date)-1), @Date) 
         And Date < DateAdd(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @Date)), @Date)
```

Comment: Where do i Close the bracket? You are missing one!